# Recording microphone and listening from ethernet

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, ethernet, microphone

I'm stuck with an audio problem.

I have an old machine (let's call it Alice) under Xubuntu, that I can use to continuously listen sounds from an external microphone plugged in the line-in jack.
I can access the machine from my PC (let's call it Bob -under Ubuntu) with ssh (and physically too ... when I will update the login keyboard layout that changed recently I don't know why, and currently prevents me from doing so).
I've tried to remotely record the microphone, unsuccessfully, with arecord, pulseaudio, but I'm new with ALSA and PA.
With PA the mic isn't listed with pacmd list-sources!?.

Is there a (simple?) way I can continuously (but in the same time, I don't have much space on the disk, max 50 GB free) record on Alice (and eventually read the records from Bob)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using VLC on "Alice" to stream the audio over RTP to a local address, then have "Bob" listen on that address + port & capture recordings of the audio. The tricky part will be identifying the MRL (media resource locator) for your audio input device.

The streaming command would look like this:

```
cvlc alsa://<input_device> --sout-keep --no-sout-video --sout="#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=<bit_rate>,aenc=ffmpeg,channels=<n_channels>,samplerate=<sample_freq>,threads=2}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=<stream_address>,port=<stream_port>,sdp=sap,proto=udp}" &
```

Where:

- `input_device` is the ALSA hardware address of your jack microphone; you can likely find this by running `cat /proc/asound/cards`; if the microphone is tied to soundcard 1, then `input_device` should look like `hw:1,0`
- `bit_rate` is optional, but should typically be 64*`n_channels` (so 64 for mono, 128 for stereo, or even 264 for superior sound quality)
- `n_channels` is the number of audio channels supported by your microphone (1 for mono, 2 for stero)
- `sample_freq` also depends on your mic; should be a value like 44100 or 48000, but could be less (units are in Hz)
- `stream_address` should be some arbitrary multicast IP address of your choice, like 239.255.12.42
- `stream_port` is also an arbitrary port of your choice, like 1234

Then, on "Bob", to receive the stream of live audio (and play it to the default audio output device), issue this command:

```
vlc -vv rtp://@<stream_address>:<stream_port>
```

Note that `cvlc` just launches VLC without the GUI, synonymous to `vlc -I dummy`.

You can then write some basic script with a loop that generates output sound file names (`out_file_name`), launches the following VLC command to listen & record the audio to that output file for some duration of time, then kills that VLC process (in this case, saving audio in WAV format):

```
cvlc --no-sout-video --sout-audio --ttl=1 --sout-keep --sout "#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=<bit_rate>,aenc=ffmpeg,channels=<n_channels>,samplerate=<sample_freq>,threads=2}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=<out_file_name>}" rtp://@<stream_address>:<stream_port> vlc://quit &
```

After each launch of the above command within your loop, simply wait for however long you want the recording to be, then kill that background listening process with either `kill -9 $!` or `pkill vlc`.

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive explanation! Comment here is limited, so I cut it dramatically.

The `cat /proc/asound/cards` gave :
` 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xdfebc000 irq 28`
, so as I hadn't enough information, I tried pacmd list-sources, which gave me (very truncated):

`2 source(s) available.
  * index: 1
 name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    index: 3
 name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo> ports: device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"`
Can I assume the mic identifier is hw:0,3 ?

Comment: Did you have any success with using `alsa://hw:0,3` as your input MRL? If that HDA-Intel device includes that microphone input, then you can use its name like this: `alsa://hw:Intel`. Try searching for input source identifiers with ffmpeg too, like this: `ffmpeg -sources`; if it shows your audio input microphone, it should include in the details `CARD=<device_name>` --> if that's the case, use `alsa://hw:<device_name>`.

Comment: Thx. Yes, I've tried with `alsa://hw:0,3`, since I presumed it was good, but I was receiving nothing. `ffmepg -sources` gives me `hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0 [Direct hardware device without any conversions]`, so I tried with `alsa://hw:Intel`, but it gave the same result. I've just tried VLC RTP in local, discovered VLC was not installed, so I installed it, then ... `hw:Intel` remains the same, but `alsa://hw:0,` exits with error codes, saying VLC is not able to open this MRL. I'm copying my cvlc command below, just to see if I'm OK. Is there a way to check if it really sending the stream ?

Comment: Here's the clvc command I'm using : `cvlc alsa://hw:Intel --sout-keep --no-sout-video --sout="#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=64,aenc=ffmpeg,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=2}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.42.42,port=65500,sdp=sap,proto=udp}" &`